# Fullscreen Exclusive Unhandled Exception

Tags: java, exception, java-2d

I am currently implementing a fullscreen-exclusive mode in my Java2D-Application. While testing on several systems (all Windows 7/8.x) with most recent (18. February 2015) JRE, I can reproduce a application crash which does NOT throw an exception:

If you are in fullscreen-exclusive mode (yes: I check for supported display modes) and turn off the monitor which displays the application, the application crashes. No exception thrown. My guess is, that the vsync-component of Java2D crashes, but I lack the required experience in Java. Can someone help me out here on how I can handle this exception (by switching back to windowed-mode for example). Something like "isDisplayDeviceReady()" might also be helpful.

Thank you for your time.

This is what Windows shows me after application crash:

Problemsignatur:

- Problemereignisname: APPCRASH
- Anwendungsname:  javaw.exe Anwendungsversion:    8.0.31.13
- Anwendungszeitstempel:   54925fd3      Fehlermodulname:  StackHash_915d
- Fehlermodulversion:  6.1.7601.18247
- Fehlermodulzeitstempel:  521ea8e7   Ausnahmecode:    c0000374
- Ausnahmeoffset:  000ce753
- Betriebsystemversion:    6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48   Gebietsschema-ID:   2055
- Zusatzinformation 1: 915d
- Zusatzinformation 2:
- 915d12e427f130d100a5a047f72f08c0
- Zusatzinformation 3: 8dd4
- Zusatzinformation 4: 8dd4ced129ecb79ce625a0ed8d82cee9

Comment: You can report it at http://bugreport.java.com/ - maybe they suggest a workaround even if they don't fix it immediately

Comment: I'll do that after some more testing. Today I tested it on yet another system where it works. I would like to collect more data before posting it as bug.